# GADT's and mtl transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, gadt

I want to use GADT's as the return value of a mtl monad transformer stack, but the GADT has a type * -> * unless constrained to a single type. The mtl stack requires a * and so it does not compile.

I have a monad transformer stack:

```
type ExceptStackCornerPointsBuilder =  ExceptT String (StateT BuilderStateData (IO)) BuilderMonadData
```

The return type of BuilderMonadData has several constructors, which must interact with each other:

```
data BuilderMonadData_GADT t where  
       BuilderMonadData_GPointIds_GADT :: [GPointId] ->  BuilderMonadData_GADT
       BuilderMonadData_CPoints_GADT :: [CPts.CornerPoints] ->  BuilderMonadData_GADT [CPts.CornerPoints]
  BuilderMonadData_Points_GADT :: [Pts.Point] -> BuilderMonadData_GADT [Pts.Point]
```

I want to use GADT's to constrain they way they interact, but I can't as the stack requires a * but using but using BuilderMonadData_GADT results in a * -> * and so it does not compile.

To get a * I need to constrain to a single BuilderMonadData_GADT constructor, but I can't as they are all required. I already have and use a BuilderMonadData without the GADT, and it works, but I can only catch bad combinations of constructors at runtime, using pattern matches and throwE from ExceptT.

Is there a way, using GADT's or some other method, to have these constraints caught at compile time, while still using an ADT with multiple constructors and types?

The code is at github.com/heathweiss/ChampCad but I still haven't pushed this code with the GADT's, and it is not likely to make master branch for a while. If requested I could get it up there.

The version without the GADT's are at:
https://github.com/heathweiss/ChampCad/blob/master/src/GMSH/Common.hs 
and
https://github.com/heathweiss/ChampCad/blob/master/src/GMSH/Builder/Base.hs

Comment: `type ExceptStackCornerPointsBuilder t =  ExceptT String (StateT BuilderStateData (IO)) (BuilderMonadData t)`?

Comment: Getting a lot of compiler errors such as:

Comment: Getting a lot of compiler errors about matching  type ‘t’ with rigid types such as ‘[CPts.CornerPoints]’. Seems like now returning a rigid type instead of a t is a problem, but I will pursue this and see if I can work it out. I think I am trying the impossible. Replacing a * with a * -> *. On the good side, type ExceptStackCornerPointsBuilder t ... does compile.

Comment: But I see that adding the actual type such as [CornerPoints] to the function declarations that return a ExceptStackCornerPointsBuilder, is cleaning up those compiler errors. This looks like it could work. Be a day or 2 before I will know. Will post the results.

Comment: Could you give more details about the kind of interactions you want to rule out? Perhaps you could point out the code throwing the runtime errors you are currently using, as examples? Why not have a separate monad for each type of points (which seems essentially what you're doing by "adding the actual type", but in a roundabout way)?

Comment: And it works. I can use a GADT for the return type of a mtl monad transformer stack. The compiler catches invalid GADT interactions.  Did it just like chepner suggested. Thanks chepner. And thanks Will Ness for cleaning up my orignal post.

Comment: Li-yao Xia: I am not sure, can I run a monad stack in a single do statement, without all of the expressions returning the same ADT. I remember trying to make that work earlier, and couldn't get it to compile. That is why I combined my different types into a single ADT by using separate constructors. As I recall the compiler could not infer a type for the function containing the do statement and so my solution was to combine them.